# Laravel upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 to 5.7: Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined

Tags: laravel, axios

AXIOS is not working anymore after upgraded Laravel from 5.5 to 5.7

Tried everything I know, like: composer update, dump-autoload, artisan config:clear, cache:clear, composer require axios, npm install axios and the error stills standing

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined
```

At the bootstrap.js file:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

And this is the app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from "vue";

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'), default);

import VueTheMask from "vue-the-mask";
Vue.use(VueTheMask);
```

What I am doing wrong?
Anybody?

Comment: Can you provide more context for the exception? Perhaps a stack trace could help

Comment: Where and how are you referencing `axios` in your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

NPM modules are independent from the Laravel upgrade. Perhaps the issue you might be facing is the cache. Try the follwing:

```
yarn cache clean    
rm -rf ./node_modules    
yarn
yarn add axios
```

If you are not using yarn, you should. Much faster and cleaner than NPM.

Comment: Try `import axios from 'axios'` and then `window.axios = axios`

Comment: Still not working. See my bootstrap.js
```
window._ = require('lodash');


try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

import axios from "axios"; 
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Comment: I´m really stuck in that... it just make no sense... do you agree?

Comment: Can you upload the project at a repo and share it? or atleast a piece on codepen

Comment: Can't, it is protected by contract!

Comment: Then sorry i cant really help you. Good luck